# remove comment_field of comment form

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to remove default `comment_field` of comment form which is required field.
I tried many ways but unable to unset this field. If this field unset not able to post comment error shown

> First write comment

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
 add_action('init', 'remove_comment_support', 100);

 function remove_comment_support() {
   remove_post_type_support( 'page', 'comments' );

   remove_post_type_support( 'post', 'comments' );
 }
```

Do the settings according to this [link.](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-turn-off-or-disable-comments-in-wordpress-pages/)